# Send Classification: Change Automatically

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, send-definition

Has anyone ever come across a scenario where the "From" field would change depending on the what was in the rows of the Data Extension?

A question was asked if we could change the "From" to different people on our sales team (rotating or maybe defined by something in the Data Extension).

Has anyone ever come across that? If it's feasible, would anyone have an idea of how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**: Yes. This can be achieved with the platform.

Pre requisites:

1. You must have the `**Subscriber Specific From**` feature enabled.
2. You must either create the attribute in Email Studio, or have a data extension that houses the fromName & fromAddress.

   and can be achieved by following these steps:
3. Create FromName and FromEmail attributes for your subscribers
4. Create a sender profile to use for these sends.
5. For the From Name of the sender profile, use this AMPscript:

> For Email Attributes.

```
%%[ifFromName != "" then]%% %%=v(FromName)=%% %%[else]%%
Default
%%[endif]%%
```

> For Data Extensions

You would need a lookup function to pick these values up.

eg

```
%%=Lookup("ReplyInformation","Name","State", state)=%%
```

For more information, visit the Sender Profiles section here: [Send Classification](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/admin/send_classifications/)